# Javascript onClick event not working to log on the console

Tags: javascript

I know I'm overlooking something but I'm stuck on knowing what I'm doing wrong. Can't seem to get the console to print out ( I'm eventually working on adding a box to the screen). I'm using Chrome btw:

HTML

```
<button id="1" class="hot"></button>
```

JS

```
function addBox() {
  console.log("hello");
}

var clickBox = document.getElementById("1");
clickBox.onClick = addBox;
```

Comment: If you're on Chrome, please use `clickBox.addEventListener("click",addBox);`. It's the current standard and should be used when supported (which IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera have already for several years now).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, Thanks for the comment, I was following the Javascript & Jquery Book by Jon Duckett and in it was showing the older ways to write it hence my old syntax (just incase I come across old code), but then it shows the new standard way, which you described in your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DOM properties are case sensitive (unlike HTML attributes) and the correct name of the property is `onclick`:

```
clickBox.onclick = addBox;
```

[Learn more about the different ways of binding event handlers.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)

---

```js
function addBox() {
  console.log("hello");
}

var clickBox = document.getElementById("1");
clickBox.onclick = addBox;
```

```css
.hot {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<button id="1" class="hot"></button>
```

Comment: This is the only incorrect way of attaching an event listener that modern browsers simply *allow* to work. Please see my answer and comment.

Comment: @JonathanGray: How can something that is standardized be "incorrect". Are there more flexible ways? Surely. But that doesn't make this "incorrect".

Comment: I'm disappointed that your answer and your link with "different ways" fail to even mention [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). I don't believe an answer about binding event handlers should be considered complete without mentioning the current standard that's been in place for several years. This one is very old, as is the resource you linked.

Comment: @FelixKling It's not standardized. It only works for backwards compatibility reasons and is likely already deprecated for many browsers.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: It seems you didn't read the article: *"More recently a third model has appeared on the scene when W3C published its [DOM Event specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/)."*, *"“How do I register event handlers to an HTML element?” There are four ways of doing this: inline, traditional, [W3C and Microsoft](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)."* This article (and of course the other articles it links to) is the most comprehensive introduction to event handling I know.

Comment: @JonathanGray: Looks pretty standardized to me and not at all deprecated: https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/webappapis.html#globaleventhandlers-globaleventhandlers

Comment: Those are HTML standards. That has nothing to do with event handling in JavaScript.

Comment: @JonathanGray: Oh please... event handling as *everything* to do with HTML and the DOM. It's simply an API that is made accessible in JavaScript.

Comment: @FelixKling I assume you read and write all of your HTML attributes directly from the DOM object? If so you're doing it wrong...

Comment: @FelixKling My point still stands. The article itself does not mention `addEventListener`, nor does it emphasize the importance of using the current standard over the old one, saying that the old one should be favored for more coverage. [Here's a good reason to use the current standard](http://www.simonewebdesign.it/onclick-vs-addeventlistener/).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: I'm well aware of the differences. All I wanted is to point out the mistake in the code, not to advocate any specific way of binding event handlers.

Comment: @JonathanGray: Not sure what the point of your comment is. I have no problem if you are against the use of the `onclick` DOM property, but please don't spread false information.

Comment: @FelixKling I find it slightly ironic but moreso hypocritical that you would imply that I have spread false information. The correct way of adding an event listener using DOM is either with `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` (for backwards compatibility with older IE browsers). The only correct way of reading and writing regular attributes using DOM is with either `getAttribute` or `setAttribute`. There is even a further more-correct way of getting and setting custom `data-` attributes. But absolutely *nothing* is standard about your implementation of handling event listeners using DOM.

Answer (score 4):

Try

`clickBox.onclick = addBox;`

or

`clickBox.addEventListener('click', addBox);`

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any native `onClick` method for DOM elements in JavaScript.

You could do an event attribute in your HTML `<button onclick="addBox()">`.

Or you could do `clickBox.addEventListener('click', addBox);`.

Answer (score 0):

First, your ID should begin with a letter (if you plan to have HTML4 compatibility). Second, if you want to define an event using JS (without a library such as jQuery), you should use `addEventListener`. Or you can simply go the route of adding `onclick` directly to the element (`onclick="addBox()"`). Finally your `onclick` should all be lowercase (as JS property keys are case sensitive).

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote? As far as I know there is nothing technically incorrect about my answer.

Comment: The only reason `.onclick` works is for backwards compatibility with bad coding practices. `.onclick` is supposed to reference the attribute of the HTML element itself as a string value. The browser only adds it as an event listener explicitly when it detects a non-string value. Otherwise an artificial event listener is created which interprets the string value.

Comment: *"The browser only adds it as an event listener explicitly when it detects a non-string value. Otherwise an artificial event listener is created which interprets the string value."* That's not correct. Try to assign a string and you will see that it won't work. Here, I did it for you: https://jsfiddle.net/g2zzwvhz . Of course if you talk about the *HTML attribute*, I agree.

Comment: @FelixKling Well, it used to work that way. Probably phased out because defining events in-line using strings is pretty much the equivalent of using `eval` and defining properties on the DOM object itself is against standards.

Comment: *"defining properties on the DOM object itself is against standards"* Well, I wouldn't say it's against standards, but it may not work correctly since DOM objects are exotic objects. But `onclick` is standardized, so there is no issue here.

Comment: @FelixKling `onclick` as an HTML property is standardized. The way the property is being set using DOM is not.

Comment: Yes it is. Here is the HTMLElement DOM API: https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#elements-in-the-dom . Note how it says `HTMLElement implements GlobalEventHandlers;` at the bottom. That's the list of event handler properties.

Comment: @FelixKling Do you not understand the context of what I am trying to explain to you? That page basically proves my point. `onclick` is an HTML attribute. NOT to be used to define event listeners *within* JavaScript itself (using DOM). `click` is used as a *string* when defining the click event. Not `onclick`.

Comment: What I showed you is an extension of the DOM API for HTML documents. Of course that API is only used for HTML documents, but that doesn't make it any less a "DOM API". Since you mentioned `data-*` attributes in another comment, you can see that this extension adds a `dataset` property to the DOM API. In exactly the same way, this definition defines the `on*` properties for DOM (HTML)Elements . If you don't consider these extensions for HTML documents as part of the DOM API, then I agree with you. However, that's the API browsers implement. No browser will only implement the "pure" DOM API.

Comment: I don't know, maybe we just misunderstand each other. I don't really care anymore.

Comment: @FelixKling The fact of the matter is that method of defining attributes using DOM is only really left around for backwards compatibility purposes. What you're doing with your code is defining an event by setting an HTML property on the DOM object itself. The DOM object is used for things like `getAttribute` amongst others, and therefore it gets messy, to say the least, to use the object itself to mess with attributes especially when the attribute definition itself is unnecessary. That's why other methods exist for attaching event listeners: https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html

Comment: Of course some DOM properties have corresponding HTML attributes. But you should not think that setting a DOM property is the same as setting an HTML attribute (I think the term "HTML property" is very misleading). Assigning a value of to the `onclick` property *does not* set HTML attribute with the same name (try `element.onclick = function() { alert(42); }; console.log(element.getAttribute('onclick'));`. However, *some* properties do have that effect (e.g. `element.id = 42;`). I don't know the rules for which properties get synced to HTML attributes though.

Comment: I always considered the HTML attributes to be the initial values for the corresponding DOM properties. But once you have a reference to the DOM element, use the DOM API to interact with the element (which means using its properties, not using `getAttribute`, etc).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113099/discussion-between-jonathan-gray-and-felix-kling).

Comment: @FelixKling "But you should not think that setting a DOM property is the same as setting an HTML attribute (I think the term "HTML property" is very misleading)." <-- This is exactly the basis behind the point that I'm trying to get across. I feel as though you're attacking my words instead of making a logical argument. I meant HTML attribute. If that isn't obvious to you, then I'm sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: @FelixKling Attributes cannot be properties of the DOM API, or any API for that matter; In fact they are arbitrary to the API. Attribute names have the possibility of colliding with actual DOM API properties and/or methods. Thus the actual DOM API provides ways of doing everything without actually referencing attributes as properties of the DOM object. The only reason you *can*, again, is for backwards compatibility with bad coding practices.

Comment: Maybe I simply don't understand what you mean.  Sure, the *property* may have been standardized in retrospect because every browser implemented it. And maybe browser implemented it because there was an HTML attribute with that name. But I have not seen it mentioned in an official document that this API is deprecated. I'd appreciate if you could provide a link. (e.g. ECMAScript defines behavior that is incorrectly implemented by browsers in a specific section that explicitly says that this behavior is only standardized because browser *currently* implement it).

Comment: Just to be clear: I'd always recommend `addEventListener` over `onclick`. I'm just against the statement  "`onclick` is deprecated" without backing up this claim.

Comment: @FelixKling I never stated that it was deprecated. I stated that it's likely deprecated. I actually didn't know that the event listeners were actually standardized as object properties to DOM by W3C. That changes the likelihood of it being deprecated (to DOM). But I think you're misunderstanding me. To be clear, I'm not implying that `onclick` itself would be deprecated, nor am I against the usage of `onclick` at all. I am simply stating that you should not be messing with HTML attributes in order to add event listeners (if you're already using JavaScript to add the listener).

Comment: Then maybe I misunderstood you all along. I completely agree that one shouldn't use the `onclick` *HTML attribute* (or at least not both as you said). However, then I don't understand your comments on my answer... But anyway, I guess that's a good stopping now before we start all over again ;) Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

this this code javascript :

```
var clickBox = document.getElementById("1");
clickBox.onclick=addBox;
function addBox() {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try giving all the javascript within window.onload tags
Like the following:

> window.onload = function(){
>      //Your Code Here
>   }

Comment: That seems unnecessary since the code is loaded after the element.